# How can I create a Typeface from a the string got by getTypeface() method?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, fonts, android-fonts

I would like to store the font details in database and when needed retrieve the font and apply the typeface to TextView?

```
userFont = text.getTypeface().toString();
```

Now I am storing the userFont in my database, and it looks like "android.graphics.Typeface@12345543"

I want to create a typeface using the userFont and apply the typeface to TextView

The expected code looks like this.

```
TextView txt = findViewById(R.id.showUserEnteredText);
Typeface font = Typeface.create(userFont);
txt.setTypeface(font);
```

Help me apply a concept like this?

Comment: `Typeface` is not a `String`, and its `toString()` is simply the `Object` implementation. You cannot create a `Typeface` object later using that `toString()` output. Since you were the one who said what typeface to use for the `TextView` in the first place, you should not need to call `getTypeface()` to determine what typeface you used.

Comment: Isnt there a way to change that string back to typeface

Comment: No, sorry. Since you were the one to change the typeface, you need to save that information at the point you made the change.